# Check/uncheck multiple checkboxes with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I´ve been stuck on a minor jquery problem, it´s probably just something minor I´m not seeing yet.  I have a PartialView and I want to be able to check a checkbox and it should make all the other checkboxes unchecked.  I only want one checkbox checked before I submit the page.

Anyway, here is my code sample:

**This is my PartialView**

```
@model List<int>
@foreach (var element in Model)
{
    <div id="AddedProductImages">
        <img src="@Url.Action("RetrieveFile", "File", new { id = element })"     alt="@element" width="125px;" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="PrimaryImage" onchange="PrimaryImageChkBox('@element')" id="PrimaryCheckbox'@element'"/>
</div>
}
```

**This is my Jquery function**

Shouldn´t I be able to uncheck first and then in the second line tell the clicked checkbox to be checked?

```
function PrimaryImageChkBox(id) {
    alert(id);
    $('input[name=PrimaryImage]').removeAttr("checked");
    $('#PrimaryCheckbox' + id).attr('checked', "checked");
}
```

Thank you in advance  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I only want one checkbox checked before I submit the page.

That's what radio buttons are meant for, not checkboxes. You could group multiple radio buttons by using the same name. This allows only a single radio button to be selected at the same time:

```
@model List<int>
@foreach (var element in Model)
{
    <div id="AddedProductImages">
        <img src="@Url.Action("RetrieveFile", "File", new { id = element })" alt="@element" width="125px;" />
        <input type="radio" name="PrimaryImage" />
    </div>
}
```

And in addition to that you could now completely get rid of javascript.

Comment: Haha, you are absolutely right.  Sometimes my brain freezes and for some reason I didn´t think of radiobuttons.  Problem solved within 5 minutes  :)